# Cursor location after zoom using svg-pan-zoom

Tags: javascript, svg, svgpanzoom

I am using the ariutta svg-pan-zoom library. I have a SVG file with `viewBox="0 0 1052.3622 744.09448"`
and div container with `width=649` and `heigth=525,59`.
I'm trying to get cursor location inside my SVG.

My code:

```
var divX = ev.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
var divY = ev.pageY - this.offsetTop;

var currentPan = panZoom.getPan();
var realZoom = panZoom.getSizes().realZoom;
var panZoomHeight = panZoom.getSizes().height;
var viewboxHeight = panZoom.getSizes().viewBox.height;

var x = (divX - currentPan.x) / realZoom;
var y = ((panZoomHeight - divY - ((panZoomHeight-(viewboxHeight*realZoom))/2) + currentPan.y) / realZoom);

var zoom = panZoom.getZoom(); // only to explain my problem - I'm not using this value
```

It works fine until `zoom` equals 1 (default zoom level). When zoom is greater than 1 the `y` value is wrong (`x` is good).
For example:

1. I click at some point and the result is `x: 197.82463543913713, y: 616.3652582594272`
2. zoom using mousewheel (`zoom: 3.9562617313728334`, cursor is still at the same point on the screen).
3. click again and the result is `x: 197.82463192575807, y: 540.7407139122004`

I've been trying many combinations of code, but nothing works good. I have no idea how to do this. Am I missing something obvious?
Is there any better solution to get cursor position?

Comment: I think the origin is top-left, so you have to do the same calculations for `x` that you did for `y`. Something like `x = (divY - currentPan.y) / realZoom;`

Comment: In my application this was also the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot! I had a bug in the other part of my code. That is why I thought that the y value was correct for `zoom == 1` - in fact it wasn't.

This works for me:

```
var y = (panZoomHeight - divY - (panZoomHeight-(viewboxHeight*realZoom)) + currentPan.y) / realZoom;
```

Comment: This did not work for me. The y calculation inverses the coordinate. This may be desired in some cases, but was not for mine.

Comment: @theMaestro73 Did you find a solution to the Problem? When I try it the y value seems to have some issue with the zoom also. (on top of beeing inversed)